# Open mail client from browser with an byte[] attachment from the server

Tags: c#, email

I looked on SO an found several ways to do kind simmilar things, but those aren't the solution.

A user is on the web page and on a click on a file (which is stored in byte[] on server) should open the mail client, where the attachment, subject and mailfrom is set.

Subject and Mail From is no problem, but the attachment. Here are some points I need/need not to:

- I cannot/I am not allowed to Create a file such as mymailmessage.eml
  on a client (access denied)
- I cannot use `MailMessage`
  (`System.Net.Mail`) because for this I need to create a file to open the mail client with `Process.Start(filename)`
- I cannot use `mailto:` because there I cannot add an attachment

So the way I am on for now is to use MAPI. Unfortunately I have not found a solution. My source is a byte[] and I can write this in a `MemoryStream`. Is it possible to create a kind of `virtual file path` in C#? But I don't know how to open the mail client including the parameters. All the MAPI projects (like https://github.com/PandaWood/Simple-MAPI.NET or https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10881/MAPIEx-Extended-MAPI-Wrapper are using local files. I tried those, but in my case the mail client isn't starting, so no mail message window is popping up.

So what I am looking for is: Create a MapiMessage with MailFrom, Subject, an attachment and then open the mail client (like with mailto) including the attachment.

An other C# project is this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17561/Programmatically-adding-attachments-to-emails-in-C

According to this codeproject, I cannot find the line, where the programm is saying the mail client please open (like `Process.Start()`) and open the prepared mail message for me.

Is there any other way except MAPI, when I only have a `byte[]` in the web application and need to open a mail client message including the attachment not storing/downloading it on the user client?

Comment: What is preventing your from creating an EML file on the server and letting the user download it?

Comment: The user wants a behavior like a mailto address, so that there is no download, that has to accepted by the user. The user should click on the file and the mail message file should open with the file in the attachment. That's the requirement and I am struggling with it..

Comment: there is no way to do that with attachments. EML file is the only workaround.